# How to store multiple Toggle button states in a Boolean Array in Android

Tags: android-activity

I have 47 Toggle buttons in my program ,Can anybody help how to store the button states (True/False) in a Boolean Array  when it is checked.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Put them into list and set tags(Which is position inside list ) on them and also set OnCheckedChangedListener on them  and getThat location when their status changes and have an array with same number of locations and update location by using the tag(which is the list location)**